# Is there a date format to display the day of the week in java?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I know of date formats such as 
`"yyyy-mm-dd"` -which displays date in format `2011-02-26`
`"yyyy-MMM-dd"`-which displays date in format `2011-FEB-26`

to be used in eg:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy/MMM/dd ");
```

I want a format which would help me display the day of the week like `2011-02-MON` or anything.  I just want the day of the week to be displayed in characters with the month and the year.  Can you tell me of a format like this?

Comment: How about just using `dd` as format?

Comment: I'm sure the API docs (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), would be happy to provide you an answer.

Comment: what do you mean "day" - day of week, day of month. In your example the whole date is displayed. Please show the exact input and output you want.

Comment: At a general advise, better use the `-` notation only with dates in the ISO format (i.e. year-month-day). The dash was elected there since it was not used for any other date formats at the time, to avoid confusion, and now everyone is using his custom ordering with the dash ...

Answer (score 431, accepted):

This should display 'Tue':

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").format(new Date());
```

This should display 'Tuesday':

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(new Date());
```

This should display 'T':

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE").format(new Date());
```

So your specific example would be:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-EEE").format(new Date());
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! What I was looking for was: Monday, 04/04/2016. So in my case, `new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy");` if it helps someone in the future.

Comment: OK, it works. `EEEE` displays whole names of day of week - i.e. 'Monday', 'Tuesday' etc.

Comment: I hadn't really considered that this site would even be around, let alone java would finally get around to bailing on Date. It does technically answer the OPs question. However, I can probably add a new section on how the new java.time stuff works

Comment: nice nice... EEEE is the complete written day's name.

Answer (score 20):

Yep - 'E' does the trick

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-E");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Comment: seeing oracle in the url of the javadocs still feels strange.

Comment: We also use: `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-EEEEEEE");` for display long DayOfWeek.

Answer (score 7):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
```

EEE stands for day of week for example Thursday is displayed as Thu.

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )
         .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-EEE" , Locale.US )  )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Note how we specify a `Locale` such as `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH` to determine the human language used to translate the name of the day.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-EEE" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

By the way, you may be interested in the standard [ISO 8601 week](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) numbering scheme: `yyyy-Www-d`.

> 2018-W01-2

Week # 1 has the first Thursday of the calendar-year. Week starts on a Monday. A year has either 52 or 53 weeks. The last/first few days of a calendar-year may land in the next/previous week-based-year.

The single digit on the end is day-of-week, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

Add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library class to your project for the `YearWeek` class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use "E"

See the section on **Date and Time Patterns**:

[JavaDocs for SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is about getting the day of week as string (e.g. the short name), but for anybody who is looking for the numeric day of week (as I was), you can use the new "u" format string, supported since Java 7. For example:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("u").format(new Date());
```

returns today's day-of-week index, namely: 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, ..., 7 = Sunday.