# How to format date with day in Android?

Tags: android, date

I want to set date in format like this,

```
Friday, March 4, 2012 3:15 AM
```

yes I am know about this

```
   SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
   Date date =new Date();
   String s = parseFormat.format(date);
```

but I don't know what is option to show day,
please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
     SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
     Date date =new Date();
     String s = parseFormat.format(date);
```

Refer this for more details [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 15):

In your format string, use "E" for the short name (Sun, Mon, Tue, etc), or "EEEE" for the full words (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc).

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121976/is-there-a-date-format-to-display-the-day-of-the-week-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String currentDateTime(String dateInParse){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
    Date date = null;
    try
    {
        date = sdf.parse(dateInParse);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
    String newFormat = formatter.format(date);

    return newFormat ;
}
```

here dateInParse is your date in string that format is like as sdf.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use E as formatter

Ex:

`SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");`