# How to print Java Date in DD/MM/YYYY with Week Day's Name

Tags: java

Printin Java Date and Day's for a Week.

Comment: At least show some effort in writing question. Or at least a `question mark`.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a date format to display the day of the week in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121976/is-there-a-date-format-to-display-the-day-of-the-week-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd/MM/yyyy").format(yourDateObject);
```

(sigh)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html