# name of the day of the week in which the month ends, and the name of the starting date in java

Tags: java

How can I know the name of the day of the week in which the month ends, if I have the name of the day in which it begins (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ...) and the month (January, February ...), for example, as I know the name of the week of January ends with you if you start on Monday.

Comment: use some of the java time classes? have you tried anything?

Comment: can you check whether this post answers your question? :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122016/2200312

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a date format to display the day of the week in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121976/is-there-a-date-format-to-display-the-day-of-the-week-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to find day-of-week of the last day in month using `java.time` classes, for example:

```
LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 1);
DayOfWeek firstDOW = firstDay.getDayOfWeek();
LocalDate lastDay = YearMonth.of(firstDay.getYear(), firstDay.getMonth()).atEndOfMonth();
DayOfWeek lastDOW = lastDay.getDayOfWeek();

LocalDate lastDay2 = LocalDate.of(firstDay.getYear(), firstDay.getMonth(), firstDay.lengthOfMonth());

LocalDate lastDay3 = firstDay.plusDays(firstDay.lengthOfMonth() - firstDay.getDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: De nada! Glad it was helpful